# Html link not clickable

Tags: html, css

My link isnt clickable on my site, louisjr.uk

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="titlew">
        <a href="welcome.html"><p> Welcome to my site!</p></a>
    </div>
    <video muted loop autoplay width="100%" height="100%">
        <source src="http://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/000/094/original/FroggerHighway.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that my css is clumsy but please help :)

i need this site up an running soon xD
all help is much appreciated:)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `z-index` to your `titlew` element, like so:

```
#titlew {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 120px;
    width: 1900px;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```